# saffron in home brewing - taste, aroma and colour

Tags: recipe-formulation

I'm planning to add some in my mead because we have the best saffron in our country.
anyone ever tried to add saffron in their mead, wine or beer during first or second fermentation?
i know it can definitely give your drink a nice orange colour but how does it taste like? how about aroma?

Comment: If you can affordably add Saffron to whatever you are brewing please try it and let us all know. I am interested to know but myself, I cannot just "throw some in there" without a substantial investment and sadly my budget is tight. I wish you luck.

Comment: @k4 nerd i added 3g of saffron to 6 liters of my mead in secondary (1g per 2 liters); started from a low amount to see how it goes...

Comment: btw 10g costs 1$ here, i heard using exceeded amount of saffron may cause nose bleed and dizziness and shouldn't use during pregnancy.

Comment: https://examine.com/supplements/saffron/

Comment: I'd be suspicious of anything that claims to be saffron and comes at $1 / 10g.

Comment: I agree with @Robert, legit saffron is pretty pricey. If you really want to use it in your brew, spring for the good quality stuff. Good in, good out!

Comment: @Robert we export saffron to the whole world that's why it's kinda cheap here.

Answer (score 3):

I once made a clone recipe of Dogfish Head's Midas Touch that called for a small saffron addition with about 15 minutes left in the boil. In that recipe in particular, the saffron replaced the traditional aroma hop addition, so naturally aroma was impacted the most in this instance.

As far as taste, I would do a test with something else in the kitchen. Maybe try adding it to some plain rice (or something with not much flavor) and see how the saffron effects the taste and smell. Using white rice as a "blank canvas" will also show you how the color will be effected. Mess around with different amounts and different "exposure" lengths to really narrow down the desired application of saffron that you want for your mead or beer. This can go a long way in developing recipes with not so traditional ingredients (and your don't run the risk of ruining an entire batch).

Just a side note: I would hazard against using too much saffron. A little bit goes a long way, so 2-3 stems are probably all you'll need for a 5-gallon batch (which is good because it's expensive!).